# MVC Application Getting Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-timeout

I am getting an error that the Execution Timeout Expired. I have reviewed the Server Profiler and I dont see any timeout events or long duration time. The Application calls the db to display a grip so I dont think it is related to a connection.
This is what I am seeing in the trace
RPC:Starting exec sp_executesql 
SP:StmtStarting
RPC:Strating exec sp_reset_connection
There is no end time so I am not sure if this is the problem.

> Why am I seeing the sp_resetConnection?

```
<ExceptionMessage>
Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) <SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>The wait operation timed out</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
</InnerException>
```

Comment: It might be because your app can't connect to the database, that's why you don't have anything in Server Profiler

Comment: What do you mean by timeout event in Profiler? When a query times out, the client API sends an attention request to cancel the query. So you will see an attention event in the trace, not a timeout.

Comment: @DanGuzman I was thinking that I would see an Lock Timeout event or Deadlock Graph events.

Comment: Add an attention event to the trace. I would expect that to precede the rpc_completed or batch_completed event on the same spid, whose duration will be the command timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to the entity framework timeout command not a SQL timeout like the Exception Type reported